# OpenGL: Will recycling a Framebuffer in a frame hurt performance?

Tags: c++, opengl, optimization, gpu, opengl-3

Is it important for GPU performance that Framebuffers not swap between being drawn to, and being sampled from in a fragment shader, frequently?  I might be able to save video memory by recycling framebuffers in a single frame, but I worry it might kneecap some paralleling optimizations the GPU might be making when the FBO writes don't depend on eachother, or just be costly in some other way.

*Background:*

In my renderer, I allocate all the framebuffers I need in the current frame, reusing the previous frame's if possible, and use them in this way:

```
FBO_0, FBO_1, FBO_n are allocated (FBO_n is the final output)

FBO_0 bind      ]_____________________ 
FBO_0 drawn to  ]                     \
FBO_n bind                             \
FBO_0 color used as a texture          Could the GPU be doing these two tasks
FBO_n drawn to with this texture       in parallel thanks to them using seperate FBO? 
                                       /
FBO_1 bind      ]_____________________/
FBO_1 drawn to  ]
FBO_n bind
FBO_1 color used as a texture
FBO_n drawn to with this texture
```

In this scenario though, it's possible to recycle FBO_0 to act as FBO_1, reducing the overall video memory I need.  This is kinda complex to do in practice and would require a lot of refactoring, so I'm researching if this going to have a downside to performance and be worth doing.

Comment: Modern GPUs are optimized for doing: clear screen, draw everything, display. Attempting to reuse anything from the previous frame is going to get in the way of what the GPU is good at. So, while *possible* it is just going to slow things down.

Comment: Also; *reading* GPU memory to CPU memory is one of the slowest things you can do. Don't do that unless you *have to*.

Comment: @JesperJuhl - I need reword that; by 'read' I meant commanding the GPU to read it as a texture in a fragment shader, not download it to the cpu

Comment: Re-Using the FBO is a perfectly fine strategy, just add proper calls to  [`glInvalidateFramebuffer()`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glInvalidateFramebuffer.xhtml) inbetween the two passes so that the driver knows that the data is no longer needed (and might be able to use a different data storage under the hood if the previous one is still in use)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be ok if you use only FBO_0 and FBO_n, like :

```
FBO_0 bind
FBO_0 drawn data1
FBO_n bind
FBO_0 color used as a texture
FBO_n drawn to with this texture

FBO_0 bind      
FBO_0 drawn data2
FBO_n bind
FBO_0 color used as a texture
FBO_n drawn to with this texture
```

In general, if you write to an object, any command you issue later will see the new value.

The few exceptions can be found into this wiki :

https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Memory_Model

But the fastest way, depends very much on the OpenGL implementation.

In your example, as the first "FBO_n draw" depends on completion of the FBO_0 draw, the implementation may starts FBO_1 draw in parallel. But you do not have that guarantee.